# Bash If statement with multiple requirements not correctly failing test

Tags: bash, centos, sh

The problem I am experience involves multiple IF statements.  For some reason the script is validating against the code below even with the settings as follows:

SSLSite is Defined as N

SSLOnly is Undefined

Subdomain is Defined as N

```
if ([[ $SSLSite == y* || $SSLSite == Y*  ]] && [[ $SSLOnly == n* || $SSLOnly == N* ]] && [[ $Subdomain == n* ]] || [[ $Subdomain == N* ]])
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To directly answer your question, the problem is your last condition: `[[ $Subdomain == n* ]] || [[ $Subdomain == N* ]]`.

The `||` here is not grouped inside the `[[ .. ]]` like in the other clauses. This gives you

```
(A || B) && (C || D) && (E) || (F)
```

where you wanted

```
(A || B) && (C || D) && (E || F)
```

The former expression is true if `F` alone is true, which is why it's validating when `Subdomain=N`

You can solve it by making the last clause `[[ $Subdomain == n* || $Subdomain == N* ]]` instead, but clearly anubhava's syntax is better.

Answer (score 3):

Your long if condition can be shortened to:

```
[[ "$SSLSite" == [yY]* && "$SSLOnly" == [nN]* && "$Subdomain" == [nN]* ]]
```

Comment: @jaypal: Thanks, hope this what OP meant.

Comment: I appreciate the shortening.  Makes it easier, however the other guy helped me understand the mistake I made better.  Thanks for your help!